# CSS NavBar not working Properly

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am developing a website. In the navbar the Menus are ok but the sub-menus are not working properly. All the submenus are dropping down from the first menu. And sub-menus are disappearing if cursor are not placed to the sub-menus very fast.

`The site preview is here` : http://ticketsbd.com/

jsfiddle link is here : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ8u7)

Comment: Hi, can you please post your code

Comment: jsfiddle link is given.
http://jsfiddle.net/pJ8u7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your stylesheet.

```
li.has-sub {position:relative;}
li.has-sub ul {top:17px;left:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Positioning has been fixed. But now sometimes before moving cursor to the sub menu it disappears.

Comment: The sub menu disappear? I am on your site and don't see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Man, if you make sub menu and menu, I recommend you for first use this css syntax:
ul > li > a{}
But not ul li a{}
Because all properties will go for all elements li and a in this parent ul.
It makes very cascading effect.
Just work with ul > li, than ul > li > a, than you can work with ul > li > ul, and so on.
It will help you do now something strange things.

For second, you should always set for parent ul and his child li next property

```
position: relative;
```

And for sub-menu ul you should always set this properties:

```
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
```

It is a minimum which you should know. So keep on this rules and you can styles menus as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:inline-block` to the following classes:

```
.wrap{
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav_list li{
    display:inline-block;
    border-left: 2px ridge #3D3B3B;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ8u7/3/)